# Using a function in Material-Table render property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I need to use a custom function in Material-Table column render property. 
The function gets called, I get printed on the console the expected results, however, the result would simply not render in the table.
Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import HraReferenceDataContext from '../context/hraReferenceData/hraReferenceDataContext';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

const EmployeeDetailsCompanyDocuments = ({ companyDocumentsData }) => {
    const hraReferenceDataContext = React.useContext(HraReferenceDataContext);
    const { companyDocumentTypes } = hraReferenceDataContext;

    const getDocumentTypeForRow = id => {
        companyDocumentTypes.forEach(type => {
            if (type.id === id) {
                console.log(type.name)
                return type.name;
            }
        });
    };

    const columnInfo = [
        {
            field: 'typeId',
            title: 'Type',
            render: rowData =>{ getDocumentTypeForRow(rowData.typeId)}, //here is the problem
        },
        { field: 'created', title: 'Created On' },

    ];

    return (
              <MaterialTable
                 columns={columnInfo}
                 data={companyDocumentsData}
                 title="Company Documents List"
               />   
    );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning inside `forEach` doesn't work.

change this function

```
const getDocumentTypeForRow = id => {
        companyDocumentTypes.forEach(type => {
            if (type.id === id) {
                console.log(type.name)
                return type.name;
            }
        });
    };
```

to

```
const getDocumentTypeForRow = id => {
  return companyDocumentTypes.find(type => type.id === id).name;
};
```

**update**

change

```
render: rowData =>{ getDocumentTypeForRow(rowData.typeId)},
```

to

```
render: rowData => getDocumentTypeForRow(rowData.typeId),
```

because you should return the value that is returned from `getDocumentTypeForRow`.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
It still doesn't want to display the value.
Just for testing, I changed the function to "const getDocumentTypeForRow = id => {
        return "display something"
 };"
And it still doesn't display anything. I think Material Table doesn't allow functions in that rendering thing.

Comment: i'm also doing the same and i can't find a way out. I think is not possible at the moment.